# How do I make one video play after another in android. My code is below

Tags: java, android

This code shows that I have two videos in my raw file and I want the second one to play after the first one finishes automatically.

```
 VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.start();

        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.badweather);

        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

        mc.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        i=1;




        VideoView videoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
        videoView2.start();

        videoView2.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.rain);

        MediaController mc2 = new MediaController(this);

        mc2.setAnchorView(videoView2);

        videoView2.setMediaController(mc2);
```

Comment: What's the problem with your codes, you need to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd suggest. The beginning of this response assumes you'd actually prefer to use a single `VideoView`. If that's not the case, see notes at the end.

Make a queue of resource uris for videos. Something like:

```
// "list" is fine for this
List<String> videoUris = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, write a code which plays a video:

```
public void playVideo(final String videoUri) {
    // hook up to video view, etc.
}
```

From here, you have maybe two choices:

### From a Completion Callback

One approach is to listen for a video completion callback, and then do something like:

```
public void onVideoCompletedCallback(final String completedVideoUri) {
    if (!videoUris.isEmpty()) {
        playVideo(videoUris.remove(0));
    }
}
```

### From a Background Thread

Alternately, you could potentially run a thread which loops through them if you implement `playVideo()` to be blocking.

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!videoUris.isEmpty()) {
            // assume playVideo() blocks until the video
            // is done playing.
            playVideo(videoUris.remove(0));
        }
    }
}.start();
```

In both cases, I've only suggested some workable approaches. There'll still be some work done to translate them into specific platform bindings on Android.

But if you're still totally lost, start by looking at [`onPlaybackStateChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.Callback.html#onPlaybackStateChanged(android.media.session.PlaybackState)), which may be roughly a drop-in substitute for whatever I called the callback, above.

## On Android O, Use the builtin Queue

Actually, since I just now pulled up that doco, it looks like `MediaController` actually already supports a queue as of Android O preview. So, third option, on Android O: use [`addQueueItem()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html#addQueueItem(android.media.MediaDescription)). But obviously since almost literally noone will be using Android O Previous here as of April 2017, option 3 is more academic than practical.

## Using k-many VideoViews

If you do actually need and want to do this, then adapt the code above to use a `SortedMap`. The map will be from resource uri to view id. In other words, from the uri to the video source, to the android id for the videoview in which to play it. The `SortedMap` is chosen instead of a `HashMap` as it will preserve the ordering of the videos into the sequence you choose to play them.

```
Map<String, Integer> videoToViewMap = new SortedMap<>();
videoToViewMap.put("android://blah/blah/video.mp4", R.id.videoView1);
// ... more
```

Several of the calls on what used to be the `videoUris` will be the same -- `isEmpty()` for example. But of course instead of doing things like `.remove()`, you'll have to write logic that removes the first item from /map/.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Do you have any easier suggestion?

Comment: @androiduser use Google